# Appropriate diagrams for styles of lingerie/swimwear tops and bottoms?

Tags: crocheting, clothing

This may be a bit of an odd question but I am a male crocheter who is trying to make lingerie and swimwear. I am wanting a diagram that shows various styles of bottoms and tops along with their associated names but out of deep respect for my wife and a desire to maintain my own standards, I want to ensure that any images displayed are not modeled on other women.
Does anyone know of any appropriate diagrams?

I am okay with it if they are diagrams of broader categories as well as specific ones. Modeled on mannequins is also totally fine.

Comment: Diagrams would also seem to allow more consistent comparison between styles avoiding different poses or body shapes.  But so would outfits modelled on mannequins

Comment: @ChrisH Yeah, I am totally fine with outfits modeled on mannequins. I honestly would even be fine if I could just get a picture of the garment itself along with what it's name is. I'm essentially looking for standard names for varying styles.

Comment: TBH standardisation is probably the hard part. Neither marketing nor fashion is known for precise or consistent terminology!

Comment: So are there no standardizations for styles at all? I can't imagine that there are none.

Comment: My knowledge is probably no more than yours, but I'm sceptical that you'll get more than broad categories to line up between different sources

Comment: You could be right. I would be okay even to know all the broad categories although I would like to get as specific as I can.

Comment: I'm wondering, crocheted fabric seems like it might be an uncommon material for lingerie and swimwear, so there might not be much in the way of premade diagrams. It might be that this is something you would have to design from scratch.

Comment: @fixer1234 It's actually been quite a trendy thing in the past decade or so! Not necessarily for swimming, but very much for festivals, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best sources for diagrams like this is Mood Sewciety. They are a fabric seller, but also have a variety of free patterns and guides to different types of skirts and sleeves that I reference regularly. They do also have a guide to [various swimsuit silhouettes](https://www.moodfabrics.com/blog/types-of-swimsuit-silhouettes/) which is illustrated entirely with drawings. Some of their pages do have photos of actual women modelling some of their swimsuit patterns, but none are present on this specific page.

Comment: (I'm not sure if this answer will be problematic on the link rot front; if anyone has ideas on how to future-proof this, I am all ears.)

Comment: So the diagrams would not be specifically designed or optimized for crochet, it would be up to the user to figure out how to translate the design into a crochet pattern? They could similarly use any available pattern? Any advice on design elements that would be easier or harder to translate to crochet?

Comment: @fixer1234 It was my read on the question that Joachim was looking for help on names of various styles, not for crochet patterns.

Comment: Good context for understanding the answer. Yeah, now that you mention it, that isn't clear in the question.  Maybe the OP will clarify what, specifically, they're looking for.